# Laravel Modal Edit

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

Good morning. A real beginner question here. I am creating a simple form. I want to open a edit model window. I suspect my script is wrong. The reason I suspect the script is if I remove the "modal-normal" from the script the modal window opens. I am getting not errors and nothing in console. I just need the edit button to be modal. I am using something else for add and delete. Thank you for any help you can provide in advance.

The Edit Button:

```html
<a data_category_id= "{{ $category->id }}"
   data-category-name="{{ $category->name }}"
   data-category-type="{{ $category->type }}"
   data-category-color="{{ $category->color }}"
   type="button" class="btn btn-alt-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal"
   data-bs-target="#modal-normal">Edit</a>
```

The Modal Window:

```html
<div class="modal" id="modal-normal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="block block-rounded shadow-none mb-0">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="..." method="POST">
                        <div class="block-content fs-sm">
                            @csrf
                            @method('PUT')
                            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit_category_name" name="edit_category_name" placeholder="Category Name">
                            <select class="form-select" id="edit_category_type" name="edit_category_type">
                                <option selected="">Category Type</option>
                                <option value="Product">Product</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" value="#902100" id="edit_category_color" name="category_color">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Script

```js
$('#modal-normal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var edit_category_name = button.data('name')
    var edit_category_type = button.data('type')
    var edit_category_color = button.data('color')
    var id = button.data('id')
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('Edit Category ');
    modal.find('.modal-body #edit_category_name').val(name);
    modal.find('.modal-body #edit_category_type').val(type);
    modal.find('.modal-body #edit_category_color').val(color);
    modal.find('.modal-body #id').val(id);
});
```

Comment: 'if I remove the "modal-normal" from the script the modal window opens' But that text appears nowhere in your script. Did you check your console for errors? Did you check the Bootstrap documentation to ensure you've configured the HTML attributes properly?

Comment: Also I cleaned up your code to remove irrelevant stuff, but looking at the original your HTML is not properly structured. It may just be a copy/paste error, but you should double check that isn't causing any problems. A proper IDE should highlight problems like that for you.

Comment: Sorry. I pasted the edited script file. I have put back the "modal-normal". It is copy and paste by from my other bladed file that does not use modal.